# vlookup for column A present in column A of all 3 dataframe

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to vlookup for column A present in column A of all 3 dataframes

My data look like and start at A, B

dfa

```
a    1
dd   3 
aa   4
```

dfb

```
c   5
zz  6
dd  7
a   8
```

dfc

```
a   33
c   44
dd  55
zz  66
```

desire output

```
a  1   a  8   a  33
dd 3   dd 7   dd 55
```

Does pandas have vlookup multiple lookup similar to what Excel has.  I see many example with 2 column not where vlookup to see Column A present in all data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `merge` with `'inner'`, I am using reduce here :-)

```
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda  x,y: pd.merge(x,y,on=['A'],how='inner'), [df1,df2,df3])
Out[533]: 
    A  B_x  B_y   B
0   a    1    8  33
1  dd    3    7  55
```

Comment: Not quite what I desire in output but very close :)

Comment: @grantwardend do not know why we need multiple columns A here ...if so you can append more :-)

Comment: Just how data has been structured.   Append?  I would have to add new cols and swap over some I think

Comment: @grantwardend that is the way :-)